# Present NSWindow as sheet from another NSWindow using beginSheet function

Tags: swift, xcode, bundle, xib, nswindow

I'm building a macOS bundle app that's running at the beginning of the login process and I want to show some information to the user in a window. I have a NSWindowController with a .xib file which it's the main window.

For that, I created an NSViewController with a .xib to define the user interface that I want to present as a sheet, but do not show any UI and never appears

Main NSWindowController looks like:

```
import Cocoa

class Main: NSWindowController {

  var sheetWindow: SheetWindow?
    
  override func windowDidLoad() {
    super.windowDidLoad()
        
    self.window!.canBecomeVisibleWithoutLogin = true
    self.window!.isMovable = false
        
    sheetWindow = SheetWindow.init(windowNibName: "SheetWindow")
  }    
    
  @IBAction func btnClick(_ sender: Any) {
    self.window!.beginSheet(sheetWindow.window!, completionHandler: { (resp) in
      ....
    })
  }
}

==================================================================================

import Cocoa

class SheetWindow: NSWindowController {

  override func windowDidLoad() {
    super.windowDidLoad()
    self.window!.isMovable = false
  }
}
```

The main window looks like:
[image]

And after click the button looks like:
[image]

I notice after "beginSheet" function is triggered the close button from the main window disappeared
NOTE: "Visible At Launch" property is unchecked in the SheetWindow .xib

Any idea what it could be happening !!!

Comment: Is `sheetWindow` a `NSWindow` or a `NSWindowController`?

Comment: @Willeke is a NSWindowController

Comment: The first argument of `beginSheet(_:completionHandler:)` is a `NSWindow`.

Comment: @Willeke yes it is

Comment: Is the sheet window XIB an identical copy of the main window XIB?